# Convert UTC Time To Local DST Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, timezone, dst, datetime-conversion

I want to convert **UTC time to local Time Zone** where Time Zone will be dyanamic.
The question is asked because I want my UTC date to get converted automatically using DayLightSaving Time. 
DayLightSaving for Adelaide on 2019-04-25 is +4 hours and standard is +5. 
This +1 hour or -1 hour should be calculated automatically.
I hava gone through all stackoverflow similar questions but could not find or relate well. so how to convert UTC date into DST date ? momemt.js can be used but plz avoid giving links in your answer. I would prefer actual function to convert dates.
Here is the actual problem,

```
`Current Date = 2019-04-25   --yyyy-mm-dd
TimeZone = Adelaide
MyUTCDate = 2019-04-25 8:30:00
ConvertedDSTTime = ?`
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for.  Are you looking for a solution that uses Moment.js? Or are you looking for a solution that does not require a library?  Also, what form of input does your data come in, and what form of output are you looking for?  Can you provide an example in actual JavaScript code?

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear from your question, but perhaps you are looking for something like this?

```
new Date('2019-04-25T08:30:00Z').toLocaleString('en-AU', {timeZone: 'Australia/Adelaide'})
//=> "25/04/2019, 6:00:00 pm"
```